# Gatsby: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

My React component is failing to do any data fetching whatsoever. On the private route with implented Auth0, I have an admin panel for the website I'm building. I have to call my Express server running locally to obtain signature from Cloudinary for further use with their UploadAPI. As soon as I hit the index route in admin panel I get an error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch
```

I have tried to deploy it to heroku, but this did not help.

#### Gatsby component

```
const Home = ({ user }) => {
  const [ClAuth, setClAuth] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('localhost:3005/auth', {
      method: 'get',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        setClAuth(result.data)
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {ClAuth && <span>{ClAuth}</span>}
      <p>Hi, {user.name ? user.name : 'friend'}!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

#### Express app

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
import express from 'express'
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary'
import cors from 'cors'

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ message: 'hello' })
})

app.get('/auth', (req, res, next) => {
  const timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)
  let signature

  try {
    signature = cloudinary.utils.api_sign_request(
      {
        timestamp,
        public_id: 'text_image',
      },
      process.env.CL_API_SECRET
    )
  } catch {
    console.log(`There was an error.`)
  }

  res.json(signature)
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App is running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: change fetch url to `http://localhost:3005/auth` ?

Comment: yup, I'm a moron ; ' d Thank You! I've been looking at this for too long and the answer was right in front of me.